# Convert string array to string with separator

Tags: java, strings

I have this little convenience method that takes an `String` array and returns an `String` where the values are separated by a provided separator (comma, pipe, etc).

For instance, if given an array with values "abc", "def" and "ghi", and a for separator we passed " | ", the end result would be `"abc | def | ghi"`.

This is the method:

```
public String getArrayAsString(String[] stringArray, String separator) {
    StringBuilder finalString = new StringBuilder();
    boolean needsSeparator = false;
    for (String s : stringArray) {
        if (needsSeparator) {
            finalString.append(separator);
        }
        finalString.append(s);
        needsSeparator = true;
    }
    return finalString.toString();
}
```

Notice that the separator must, as its name implies, separate values, and not be appended or prepended artificially to the final `String`. So, for instance, the following would be incorrect return values: `"abc | def | ghi | "` or `" | abc | def | ghi"`.

I specifically don't like the `needsSeparator` flag variable, but without it, the unwanted leading or trailing separators would be added, and then I would need to remove them from the `finalString` before returning it, which I also don't find to be very elegant.

Is there a more concise (perhaps more elegant) way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before I review your code I want to point out that Java has a [`String.join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) method which does exactly that. Now to your code:

You use `StringBuilder`, good. You take care of not appending a `seperator` after the last and not prepending before the first element, also good. You don't handle `null` values though, it's your decision if you want to handle them separately or just let Java just throw a NPE. For the separator however, a `null` appends literally `null` to the `String`, I'd rather default to `""` if `separator` is `null`. A way to get rid of the flag:

```
public String getArrayAsString(String[] stringArray, String separator) {
    if(stringArray == null || stringArray.length == 0) return "";
```

With this we already ensured that our `stringArray` has *at least* one entry. What we can do now is initialize the `StringBuilder` with the first `String`:

```
    StringBuilder finalString = new StringBuilder(stringArray[0]);
```

Since **all** strings after the first one need to prepend the separator, we don't need the flag anymore. Unfortunately, we can't use a foreach loop, since we have to start at index 1 as the element at index 0 is already in the `StringBuilder`:

```
    for(int i = 1; i < stringArray.length; ++i)
        finalString.append(separator).append(stringArray[i]);
```

And then just return what we got:

```
    return finalString.toString();
```

Whole function:

```
public String getArrayAsString(String[] stringArray, String separator) {
    if(stringArray == null || stringArray.length == 0) return "";

    StringBuilder finalString = new StringBuilder(stringArray[0]);

    for(int i = 1; i < stringArray.length; ++i)
        finalString.append(separator).append(stringArray[i]);

    return finalString.toString();
}
```

Edit:

In `String.join()` the parameters are swapped, so the `separator` comes first, the array second:

```
    String[] arr = new String[]{"Hello", "World"};
    System.out.println(String.join(" | ", arr));
    System.out.println(getArrayAsString(arr, " | ")); //Your function
```

Output:

```
Hello | World
Hello | World
```

[Working code at ideone.com](https://ideone.com/goDLT2)

Comment: Didn't know about `String.join()`. I just saw that it works taking an array of Strings as an argument. Beautiful!

Answer (score 2):

I would probably drop an enchanced loop, and stick to indices:

```
    finalString.append(stringArray[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < stringArray.size(); ++i) {
        finalString.append(separator);
        finalString.append(s);
    }
```

You *may* try to keep the enchanced loop by wrapping the array into a `List`, get a `List.sublist(1)`and iterate over it. However I am not sure it is more concise/elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Much is already said, i.e. about `join`.

My point would be the possibility of adding something to the API usage with varargs:

```
public static String arrayAsString(String separator, String... strings) {
```

Optimizing StringBuilder with an adequate initial size, so hopefully no reallocations need to be done.

```
    StringBuilder finalString = new StringBuilder(stringArray.length * 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

Minor thing: I find *finalString* isn't a good name for that. Yes, that builder is used to *create* that "final" string, but it **isn't** itself the final string.

So, maybe, *builder* something alike would be more "telling".